# Inserting large BSON objects does not work

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson

I am trying to write a program in C++ to read, manipulate, and update my database.  I am having a problem inserting my data into mongo.  So for my work flow, I get some type of request to update a document.  I query the document, and update the data.  I then try to do an update on the document.

I have a function that converts my class object to a BSONObj through a BSONObjBuilder.  I seem to be having a problem with large arrays of sub-objects. For example, I have a field in my document called geo that looks like this:

`geo: [{"postal": 10012},{"postal":10013},...,{"postal":90210}]`

and is stored in C++ as:

`std::vector<mongo::BSONObj> geo;`

this field might have thousands of postal codes in it. When doing:

`db.get()->update("db.collection",BSON("id"<<id_), BSON($set<<updateObj));`

where updateObj is the obj I got from my BSONObjBuilder, nothing is updated in mongo. If I remove the geo field, everything is inserted.

I tried to just do

```
db.get()->update("db.collection",BSON("id"<<id_), BSON($set<<BSON("geo" << geo)));
```

thinking maybe it necessary to do separate queries due to the size of the obj and this also result in no update.

I was wondering if somehow I was hitting some sort of BSON size limit in C++.

The only reason I believe it is a size limit is because while trying to debug this problem, I tried to call updateObj.toString() in order to print out the object I was trying to insert and it threw an exception: `Element extends past end of object`.  I assume that this means I hit some type of max size of an object/element.

Any insight into this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have figured it out.  What happened was I got the geo field in one function, stored it in a vector and was using it in another.  I did not used .Obj().copy() while storing the object in the vector, I just stored the .Obj() from the query results and when I went to insert I guess the invalid pointers blew up the BSONObj and caused an error.